# (ConEmu + Cygwin) How to change tab name of ConEmu from within a cygwin bash script

Tags: bash, cygwin, conemu

i've configuring my ConEmu + Cygwin enviroment. I've created a task, when i start it in a tab, the task will run a batch file, which in turn will change dir into cygwin and run

```
bash --login -i my_ssh_entry_script.sh
```

Inside `my_ssh_entry_script.sh`, it will read a config file in my home directory then print a menu for me to select which host to connect. And finally

```
...
exec ssh -p$port $userhost
```

Now i can work on the selected machine in the same conemu tab. This works fine. And the script also works on linux machine too.

But there is a little flaw. I can't change the tab's title. I've tried to change it to:

```
....
exec $(cygpath ${ConEmuDir})/ConEmu.exe /cmd ssh -p$port $userhost -cur_console:t:$title
```

But this will always create a new tab. Any suggestion to slove it? Thanks~

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1) You need GuiMacro, thoroughly described in the project wiki:
http://conemu.github.io/en/GuiMacro.html

```
ConEmuC -GuiMacro Rename 0 "Title"
```

2) You do not need to run batch. It causes extra and useless cmd.exe in yours process tree. You can do all required "CD" and "SET" from the task content directly.

Comment: Great, it works! And there's no need to run batch indeed. Thanks @Maximus, thanks for your awesome tool ;-)

Comment: Becaue Google Code has migrated now to Github and the provided URL from Maximus isn't anymore correct the new Url for more information: [http://conemu.github.io/en/GuiMacro.html](http://conemu.github.io/en/GuiMacro.html)

Command works still.

Answer (score 4):

At least for cmd shell: 
**"-new_console:d:C:\Users\dir_name" cmd /V /K -new_console:t:Tab_renamed**